# Progress of 'catalogsearch_fulltext' reindex with SOLR?

Tags: indexing, solr, ee-1.14.0.1

I'm using EE 1.14.01 and have integrated Magento with a SOLR instance.

Is there any way to see the progress when I re-index 'catalogsearch_fulltext'? It typically takes several hours (we have a lot of products and stores) but I currently have no way of knowing how many products have been re-indexed, whether the process has stalled, etc.

If I tail the Tomcat log on the SOLR server, I can see 'update' requests being passed through but I can't see how many products have actually been indexed vs. how many remain.

Many thanks in advance,
Rick.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, I'll need to dig the code out from a store we implemented this on.

However, it sounds like you are trying to fix a symptom, not the problem. It's not normal for a reindex to take more than minutes, let alone hours.

Magento 1.9 EE was capable of a SOLR reindex of ~250k products (with 1 store view) in around 15 minutes on basic hardware (4 Cores/32GB RAM). 1.14 should be faster still.

Either your catalogue is truly enormous, or your server configuration is at fault.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback - I'd definitely be interested in seeing that code if possible. We have around 35,000 products but 160 (!) products, so the times seem comparable!

Comment: You have `35,000 products but 160 products`? Do you mean 160 store views?

Comment: Sorry yes, 160 store views.